# Expanding the Square of a Linear Operator - Linear Algebra Question for Quantum Mechanics

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

I have taken linear algebra and have some experience with basic application to quantum mechanics. I am reading a paper in quantum mechanics and am having trouble following some of the math. Here is a [link](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54563869e4b07b34ee649b68/t/54cf9882e4b02ea7650e1ec0/1422891138011/007.+1-s2.0-0375960192908198-main.pdf) to the paper. Here I refer to equations (5) and (6) on page 412.

I am given a vector $\Psi$ and operators $A, A', B,$ and $B'$. A fifth operator is defined:

$ F = A \otimes B + A \otimes B' + A' \otimes B - A' \otimes B' $.

It is shown that $\Psi$ is an eigenvector of $F$ with eigenvalue $2 \sqrt{2}$.

Then $ F^{2} \Psi = 8 \Psi \implies i(AA' - A'A) i(BB' - B'B) \Psi = 4 \Psi $.

The first equality is trivial, but I do not understand why it implies the second. I attempted to expand $F^{2}$ but don't see a relationship with $i(AA' - A'A) i(BB' - B'B)$. Can someone help me to understand this?

I have tried asking others and searching online, but I have failed to find adequate search terms.

I should note that $i(AA' - A'A)$ and $i(BB' - B'B)$ are referred to in the paper as Hermitian combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is in an additional assumption between (4) and (5):

> At the beginning, it is convenient to restrict the eigenvalues of the operators $A$, $A'$, $B$ and $B'$ to $-1$ and $1$ only.

Thus as $A$,$A'$,$B$ and $B'$ are Hermitian operators we can deduce that:
$$A^2=A'^2=B'^2=B^2=I$$
So:
\begin{equation}
(AB+AB'+A'B-A'B')^2=((A+A') B +(A-A')B')^2=(A+A')^2B^2+(A-A')^2 B'^2+(A+A')(A-A')BB'+(A-A')(A+A')B'B=(AA'+A'A+2 I)+(2I -AA'-A'A)+(A'A-AA')BB'+(AA'-A'A)B'B
\end{equation}
thus:
$$F^2=4 I -(AA'-A'A)(BB'-B'B)$$
And:
$$F^2 \psi= 8 \psi=4\psi+i(AA'-A'A)i(BB'-B'B) \psi$$